# Nuxt.js и Mongodb - как лучше с ними работать?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, mongoose, nuxt.js

Я новичок в программировании.
На данный момент изучаю стек технологий связанных с Vue.js
и меня интересуют такие вопросы:

1) Как лучше всего работать с базой данных MongoDb?
(если использовать NUXT.js)
Есть ли у NUXT.js какие то дополнительные возможности для этого?
Через что лучше запросы отсылать - через Axios или через Vue-resouce?
(Может ссылка есть у кого то связанная со всеми вышеописанными моментами.)

2) Нужно ли изучать ОРМ(как я понимаю в тренде mongoose)?
(опять же есть ли у Nuxt.js какие то плюшки облегчающие работу в этом плане.
Как минимум установку или деплой.)
Если есть ссылки на статьи с такими командами(в командной строке) - буду признателен.

3) Если работать с базой данных(не удаленной - по типу Firebase) - возможно ли статическое(static) развертывание проекта у Nuxt.js?
Или же в этом случае есть возможность только в режиме SPA делать развертывание?
(и возможно в Universal)